# Replace "Loading..." message in ListFragment when list is empty

Tags: android-fragments

I have two ListFragments next to each other. 
The left one shows categories to be selected while the right on shows the elements in the selected category.

Now at the very start of the screen the left ListFragment shows all categories while the right one is empty and waits for a category to be selected. Only then it can display the memebers of the selected categry.

While it's empty however, the "Loading.." message gets display - which I think looks quite good.

All I like to do now is replace the "Loading..." text by my own.

Is this possible without having to implement the complete ListFragment class?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ListFragment.setEmptyText(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#setEmptyText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) should do the trick!

Comment: I put the line in onActivityCreated of the ListFragment but it doesn't change anything. Even though it says otherwise in the docs! (thanks for the very good idea!)

Comment: that's odd. I should note that I don't get "Loading..." text in my ListFragments with no data, just a spinning loading animation. Is this a standard ListView? What's the xml code for your layout?

Comment: its just a normal ListFragment, not a ListView in an Acticvity

Comment: @Espiandev That is the normal behavior.

Comment: I get `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't be used with a custom content view` when trying to use `setEmptyText`.  I am using the `support` library.

Comment: @mattblang you should call it in onActivityCreated.

Answer (score 1):

The method `setEmptyText` shows a `TextView` when the list is empty therefore "Loading..." will not be shown. From Documentation

> The default content for a ListFragment has a TextView that can be
>   shown when the list is empty. If you would like to have it shown, call
>   this method to supply the text it should use.

whereas *spinning loading animation* is an indeterminant progress indicator and is normally shown as per the docs

```
public void setListShown (boolean shown)
```

> Since: API Level 11 Control whether the list is being displayed. You
>   can make it not displayed if you are waiting for the initial data to
>   show in it. During this time an indeterminant progress indicator will
>   be shown instead.
>
> Applications do not normally need to use this themselves. The default
>   behavior of ListFragment is to start with the list not being shown,
>   only showing it once an adapter is given with
>   setListAdapter(ListAdapter). If the list at that point had not been
>   shown, when it does get shown it will be do without the user ever
>   seeing the hidden state.
>
> Parameters shown  If true, the list view is shown; if false, the
>   progress indicator. The initial value is true.